# Javascript alert() in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I have a regular javascript alert() in chrome browser 12.0.742.112 
This should alert it, correct? 
I'm testing something is all browsers and I get the alert pop-up notification in everything but chrome.

Is there something I have to turn on?

edit...

Here is the code...

```
alert();
```

it is in a regular *.js file.

Javascript is not turned of because the javascript is working on the page.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: alerts work fine in chrome.  You're sure it's not something else?

Comment: how did this question get 2 upvotes

Comment: Code will probably be needed to answer this question properly.

Comment: Add some text in alert and it should work alert('test')

Comment: It should just create a message box saying 'undefined shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that you have a line of code that doesn't work in Chrome, causing it to throw an exception and never hit your alert.

In the latest Dev version of Chrome (14), `alert()` should show `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then yes 'alert();' will pop up a window that reads 'undefined' in Chrome 12 (and I imagine other versions also).

The only thing I can think of without seeing some code is that you have javascript turned off in Chrome? Most likely there is an error else where in the Javascript that only appears in Chrome. Try using the developers console to see what happens when the alert should happen (the 'Console' tab of Chrome's developer tools shows js errors).

Answer (score 2):

There must be syntax error in script. Other browser (mostly IE) supports running script till code where error is reached, but chrome does not handle that way. try to see tools > JS console, if there is some error. Also some version of chrome does not support blank alert(), while other browser do.

Comment: *"Also some version of chrome does not support blank alert(), while other browser do."* What version(s) would that be? Reference? Certainly not the Chrome 12 he said he was using.

Comment: Not sure about version, i usually use alert to debug, so found this issue. Then it was gone with chrome update, now I don't try alert anymore so not sure if it is still unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

What I found is that after the first alert() pop-up I must have clicked "[x] Don't show popus anymore for this website". And so it did.

So maybe reset that boolean setting somewhere?